# Duplicated Style Sheet Effect on Performance

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

If I have a single page that defines a style sheet.  For sake of argument lets say this style sheet has over 4,000 rules. This is defined in the head of the HTML.

```
<link href="Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Lets say a control somewhere within the page is adding a link to the same style sheet.  Because of caching (hopefully) the browser should be aware that it doesn't need to fetch the resource. However, is the browser smart enough to dump the duplicated rules? Or have I just doubled the amount of element rule checking?

**I know the practices stated are not standards and should be avoided.** I am looking to see if anyone has any insight on how the browser handles this situation.

---

### What I've tried

In Chrome I created a page with a single style sheet resource. I then ran Speed Tracer and saw the rendering time was ~0ms.  I then added the stylesheet a thousand times to the page dumped cache and reloaded. The page rendering time jumped to 78ms. Nothing crazy, but it would allude that the browser will add each style sheet to the list of rules to check per element.

Comment: Yes, browsers will cache css files (at least if this is not disabled by browser's configuration). Addind the CSS file with a button action will have the same effect When there would be a page reload - it will fetch the CSS in the browsers cache. About the impact of CSS there is a nice article to read : http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: I know more rules cause performance issues. I just wondered if the browser was smart enough to ignore duplicated rules found in duplicated style sheets.